# Writing a partitioned parquet file with SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I've got two scripts, one in R and a short second one in `pyspark` that uses the output. I'm trying to copy that functionality into the first script for simplicity.

The second script is very simple -- read a bunch of csv files and emit them as partitioned parquet:

```
spark.read.csv(path_to_csv, header = True) \
     .repartition(partition_column).write \
     .partitionBy(partition_column).mode('overwrite') \
     .parquet(path_to_parquet)
```

This should be equally simple in R but I can't figure out how to match the `partitionBy` functionality in `SparkR`. I've got this so far:

```
library(SparkR); library(magrittr)
read.df(path_to_csv, 'csv', header = TRUE) %>%
  repartition(col = .$partition_column) %>%
  write.df(path_to_parquet, 'parquet', mode = 'overwrite')
```

This successfully writes one parquet file for each value of `partition_column`. The issue is the emitted files have the wrong directory structure; whereas Python produces something like

```
/path/to/parquet/
  partition_column=key1/
    file.parquet.gz
  partition_column=key2/
    file.parquet.gz
  ...
```

R produces only

```
/path/to/parquet/
  file_for_key1.parquet.gz
  file_for_key2.parquet.gz
  ...
```

Am I missing something? the `partitionBy` function in `SparkR` appears only to refer to the context of window functions and I don't see anything else in the manual that could be related. Perhaps there's a way to pass something in `...` but I don't see any examples in the documentation or from a search online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partitioning of the output is not supported in Spark <= 2.x.

However, it will be supported in SparR >= 3.0.0 ([SPARK-21291 - *R partitionBy* API](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21291)), with the following syntax:

```
write.df(
  df, path_to_csv, "parquet", mode = "overwrite",
  partitionBy = "partition_column"
)
```

Since [corresponding PR](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/22537/files) modifies only R files, you should be able to patch any SparkR 2.x distribution, if upgrading to development version is not an option:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/apache/spark.git
git checkout v2.4.3  # Or whatever branch you use
# https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/cb77a6689137916e64bc5692b0c942e86ca1a0ea
git cherry-pick cb77a6689137916e64bc5692b0c942e86ca1a0ea
R -e "devtools::install('R/pkg')"
```

In the client mode this should be required only on the driver node.

but these are not fatal, and shouldn't cause any serious issues.

Comment: looks like the partition by argument was addressed 7 months ago? I'm not at my machine so I can't check the release... the `partitionBy` argument is not in the latest release? (I'm working on 2.3.1 btw)

Comment: It is not. Fix version is 3.0, and the latest release is 2.4.3.

Comment: thanks. a glance at the PR suggests it's already doable... will test later

Comment: Yes, this is pretty easy to do. I've edited the answer to add the insturctions.

Comment: Oh, actually I meant something even less involved. Literally just copy-paste [the method definition in the PR](https://github.com/huaxingao/spark/blob/f6b13bf6559f1f26a9556b735c2926e9ea927f87/R/pkg/R/DataFrame.R#L2975-L3005) and then pull out `callJMethod = SparkR:::callJMethod` and ditto `setWriteOptions` and `handledCallJMethod` and it works without needing to update the package even